Google Sheets formula not working as intended
I wrote this formula on excel to return specific values based on the conditions inputted. However, after writing the formula on google sheets it doesn't seem to work as it does on excel. It only takes the first condition such as "1", "LR0", "C", etc... but doesn't read the other "criteria"... Does anybody know why it does not work?
=IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"LR0","R90","R91","PW0"})\*AND(LEN(B3)={8}),"Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga Series","")&
IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","B","C","D","F","G","H","J"})\*AND(LEN(B3)\<{8}),"Dell Latitude 3100 Series","")&
IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z"})\*AND(LEN(B3)\>={9}),"Apple iPad","")&IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"5CG","5DB"})\*AND(LEN(B3)={10}),"HP X360 11 EE","")

Tried editing the formula based on some information that I found searching on google. I'm not very proficient on google sheets.

your formula is an array formula. In Excel array formulas are enabled by default but in Google Sheets you have to manually enable them. Try: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"LR0","R90","R91","PW0"})*AND(LEN(B3)={8}),"Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga Series","")& IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","B","C","D","F","G","H","J"})*AND(LEN(B3)<{8}),"Dell Latitude 3100 Series","")& IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z"})*AND(LEN(B3)>={9}),"Apple iPad","")&IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"5CG","5DB"})*AND(LEN(B3)={10}),"HP X360 11 EE",""))

try:
=LET(β, B3,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(β, "(?i)^(LR0|R90|R91|PW0)")*(LEN(β)=8),  "Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga Series", )&
 IF(REGEXMATCH(β, "(?i)^[1-9B-DF-J]")      *(LEN(β)<8),  "Dell Latitude 3100 Series", )&
 IF(REGEXMATCH(β, "(?i)^[CDF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]") *(LEN(β)>=9), "Apple iPad", )&
 IF(REGEXMATCH(β, "(?i)^(5CG|5DB)")        *(LEN(β)=10), "HP X360 11 EE", ))



remove (?i) if it should be case-sensitive
wrap it into INDEX and change B3 to B3:B if needed


or if you prefer it longer:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"LR0","R90","R91","PW0"})*AND(LEN(B3)=8),"Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga Series",)&
 IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","B","C","D","F","G","H","J"})*AND(LEN(B3)<8),"Dell Latitude 3100 Series",)&
 IF(OR(LEFT(B3,1)={"C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z"})*AND(LEN(B3)>=9),"Apple iPad",)&
 IF(OR(LEFT(B3,3)={"5CG","5DB"})*AND(LEN(B3)=10),"HP X360 11 EE",))

